# Creating new words

Tags: word-formation, portmanteau-words

A student told me a speaker came to his company and was very interesting.  This came up in the context of his preparation for a presentation about his company.  In looking at the material the speaker had, I saw his logo which said "infelligent."  At first I thought this was a typo but it was clearly intentional.  I even asked my student to spell out the letters, and he did, actually saying the "f" as a "t", then stopped after a moment and said "Eh? Why is this an f?"

I checked the [website](http://www.infelligent.com), and the owner is combining "influence" and "intelligent" into one word, a portmanteau (a la James Joyce), to create the idea of intelligent influence.

To me, this doesn't work.  If I were asked to do this, I would create "influegent" but feel like I was channeling Lewis Carroll.  You can't just smash two words together to create a new word...can you?  I don't think so.  My question is, "why not?"  Or, you can but there are some unconscious rules about this.

Comment: Usually a blend word is the combination of one or more syllables or two or more letters from two different words e.g. *sitcom* (**sit**uational **com**edy); *smog* (**sm**oke f**og**). *brunch (**br**eakfast l**unch**) The business owner only substituted one letter, it's not clear at all that the F stands for *influence*

Comment: Anyone can "invent" a new word.  Getting it accepted into the lexicon is a different matter.  Words only become accepted if they serve a need, and I see no need for "infelligent", other than as a (rather lame) gimmick for this speaker.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a grammar rule that defines the properties of a legally accepted word](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/157570/is-there-a-grammar-rule-that-defines-the-properties-of-a-legally-accepted-word)

Comment: @curiousdannii It's food for thought but I'm not sure it addresses this...maybe the list of rules that was quoted, in the sense that this word doesn't work because the syllables are wrong.

Comment: This is a company name, so it doesn't even have to be a word. _Google_ wasn't a word when the company was formed (the name was a deliberate misspelling of _googol_). It's very common to for company names to be non-words -- they're more distinctive, and allow for better trademark protection.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't see it that way.  That makes sense.

Comment: Pity the question is closed as I would have fancied answering it.  There are patterns in English, and there are common ways of creating "new" words,  and I listed a few of these. The reason why  *infelligent* cannot be classed as a portmanteau or blend word is because *influence* and *intelligent* share the same prefix, *in*, so it looks like only one letter has been substituted.  Although the two suffixes -ence and -ent are different, if you tag *-ence* onto "intelligent", you get *intelligence* which is already a word. *Influgent*  would at least appear to be a nonce word.

Comment: I would argue that *infelligent* is similar to a typo, your student  didn't even realize there was a "spelling mistake" until you pointed it out to him. I found a dictionary entry which lists *infelligent* as a (common?) typographical mistake: http://www.finedictionary.com/intelligent.html But of course there is no rule that states misspelt words cannot be coined. It happens all the time e.g. *nite* and *lite* are just two.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. It is such common practice, there's even a word for it as you mention in your question (definition from the [online MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/portmanteau)):

> 2
>
> :  a word or morpheme whose form and meaning are derived from a blending of two or more distinct forms (as smog from smoke and fog)

There are [many, many such words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_portmanteaus) that are in common use, including:

- smog
- fandom
- glitterati
- cheeseburger
- avionics
- brainiac
- carjack
- guesstimate
- bit
- codec

Some of them, such as *bit* and *cheeseburger* are extremely common. Others, less so. Whether or not a particular portmanteau word "works" depends on the specific words and how they have been combined. Often, new ones sound horrible at first but repeated usage leads to their canonization.

So, yes, of course you can mash two words together to get a new one. There are no rules, as such, only new ones and known ones.

Comment: So, for you "infelligent" works and it's just a matter of time before we all accept it?  As a native speaker I can understand "brainiac" and all the other examples you cite...but the brainiac in me can't get my head around "infelligent."  It's not playing by the rules.  Why can't I mix intelligent and design to make Indesignigent?

Comment: @michael_timofeev no, it doesn't work for me either. That doesn't mean it's not "allowed". There are no rules, some just work, others don't. And yes, if this were to become commonplace, it would start to "work" for us as well. For example, many of those listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_portmanteaus) are just awful as far as I'm concerned. Including relatively popular ones such as _edutainment_ and _guesstimate_. They just don't work for me, I find them ugly and absurd. Nevertheless, they are quite commonly used.

Comment: A decent blend word will have recognizable elements that a native speaker will be able to decipher. *Guesstimate* works because it combines *guess* and *estimate*, likewise *edutainment* which, without looking and having never heard of, I predict stems from *education* and *entertainment*. Now I've heard of *glitterati* and I can guess one of the words if *glitter* but I'm at a lost what the other is. The OP's *infelligent* is pretty bad, who would possibly guess that the F stands for inFluence?That makes no sense. *Brunch*, *cheeseburger*, *motel* etc.  make sense, and fill a void.

Comment: @Mari-LouA absolutely. As I said in my comment to the OP, _infelligent_ is absolutely awful. The only point I'm trying to make here is that there are no rules. Many of the awful ones are now common, sadly, so I very much doubt anyone will be able to describe any rules for the creation of portmanteaus.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I agree, that's why I thought "influegent" would be better.